# Launch an application from a folder Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have unzipped a folder which contains an application.
My folders name is HUGIN_LITE..
How do I run it?
I have a file which is to be used for the HUGIN LAUNCHER

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# HUGIN LAUNCHER 
# This file is assumed to be located in the "bin" folder in the HUGIN dir
#
DIR=`dirname $0`
$DIR/../gui/bin/java  --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=synthetica.base --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.table=synthetica.base --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.plaf.synth=synthetica.base --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=synthetica.base --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=synthetica.base --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=synthetica.base --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.tree=synthetica.base --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=synthetica.base --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=synthetica.base --add-exports=java.base/sun.security.action=synthetica.base -splash:$DIR/../gui/images/splash_init.gif -DHUGINHOME=$DIR/../gui -m COM.hugin.HGUI/COM.hugin.HGUI.HuginLauncher "$@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you run an executable command by providing the full file name (i.e. location and path) to the executable file.

In practice, many executables are located in folders where the system seeks for executables. These folders are listed in the PATH environmental variable. You can see the contents of that variable with the command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Any executable placed in one of the folders listed in PATH can be executed by just typing the file name of the executable.

You have a specific application unzipped in a folder. You have "a file to be used as a hughin launcher". Since you do not specify neither the folder where the program is downloaded, neither the name of the executable, I will assume the program is downloaded in the folder `~/Downloads/Hugin-lite`. I assume that the executable is called `hugin`, and I know from the information you do give that that will be located in a folder `bin` under `~/Downloads/Hugin-lite`.

Then you would launch the executable by typing its full path:

```
~/Downloads/Hugin-lite/bin/hugin
```

You can also use relative paths. For example, if your current directory is your home directory, then

```
Downloads/Hugin-lite/bin/hugin
```

will also work.

Linux will never, for security, look in the current folder for an executable. So if you are in the folder `~/Downloads/Hugin-lite/bin`, just typing `hugin` will not work, even if the executable is right there in the current directory. In that case, you explicitly need to indicate the system to find the executable in the current folder as:

```
./hugin
```

For convenience of the user, programs installed using software center have install routines that set up a launcher that causes the application to appear in the menu system, and set up an executable in one of the directories of the PATH. Such executable can be a wrapper script or even a symbolic link.